# Why did Ghosha's personal prayer become part of RigVeda?

Tags: rig-veda, prayer

*from wikipedia :* 
Ghosha was born during the Vedic period in India. Her father was Kakshivat and grandfather was Dīrghatamas and both of them had written hymns in the Rigveda. She was suffering from a skin ailment and was confined to the house attending to her father. According to a hymn, she suffered from leprosy, which had disfigured her. She was thus a celibate for a long period. She fervently prayed to Ashvins, the divine physician twins of the time, who were proficient in rejuvenation. They taught her Madhu Vidhya, a Vedic teaching, a science of secret learning to restore youth and acquire immense knowledge, to get her cured of skin ailment. Because of her constant prayers Ashvini Kumars cured her skin problem and restored her beauty. She was then married. She had a son, Suhstya, who also composed a hymn in the Rigveda.

Ghosha composed two hymns in praise of the Ashvini Kumars which are contained in two suktas (hymns) of the tenth Mandala (book) of Rigveda, chapter X hymns 39 and 40, each containing 14 verses. The first hymn praises the Ashvins. The second hymn is a personal desire expressing her intimate feelings and desires for married life.[6][7][8] The two hymns are:[9]

> “ Asvins Your radiant Chariot -whither goes it on its way? Who decks
>   it for you, Heroes, for its happy course starting at daybreak visiting
>   each morning every house, borne hitherward through prayer unto the
>   sacrifice?    ” “ Where are you, Asvins, in the evening, where at morn?
>   Where is your halting place, where rest ye for the night? O Heroes,
>   this I beg of you. 'Be near me in the day, be near me in the night'.

**I felt touched and inspired  by her story , because it is very sentimental in nature. As we all go through life, we too face lots of issues and we too do a lot of prayers to god.
But I still fail to understand how and why her prayers became immortalized in vedas, considering it was personal in nature,  and what are its larger implications ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prayer of Brahmavadin Gosha can be found in Mandala 10 of rig-Veda. Your basic enquiry is why this prayer is included in Rig-Veda. I have prepared some points by looking at the mantras and will try to give answer according to them.

> आ वामगन सुमतिर्वाजिनीवसू नयश्विना हर्त्सु कामायंसत | 
>  अभूतं गोपा
>   मिथुना शुभस पती परियार्यम्णो दुर्यानशीमहि ||[**Rv. 10.40.12**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v10.47)
>   ||
>
> ā vāmaghan sumatirvājinīvasū nyaśvinā hṛtsu kāmāayaṃsata | 
>   abhūtaṃ ghopā mithunā śubhas patī priyāaryamṇo duryānaśīmahi ||
>
> O Ashwinikumaras full of wealth and food. Be pleased with us , be
>   helpful to us in fulfilling our desires ,be graceful to us. **Let us**
>   decorate the home of husband by becoming his beloved.

- It is like a short story of miracle of Ashwini-Kumaras curing Gosha of her skin problem and restoring  her beauty.
- Here she wants to be beautiful not just because for personal reasons but as we can see it's said in the Mantra 2 that "A beautiful women is cause of Husbands respect among society and  increases it. She want to become one for that reason.
- This verse also is  significant in representing position of women in Vedic time. As independent thinkers ,she here wants a husband of her desire that mean she is looking for some qualities in him. And not just a husband of any kind. As she was a Brahmavadini (speaker or proclaimer of Brahmana and led a purposeful spiritual life.) its also is possible that she was desiring a  well educated husband withwhich she could participate in  philosophical debates.
- This Hymn still can be used (by priests)  for  the girls who wants to get married. Also  Notice the word "we" in the Mantras This Hymn is not merely a  personal request **but a classic example of universal prayer  for the girls who wants  to get married and want  husband of their desire.**

  ---

  So its quite possibe that due to above reasons her personal prayer is included in highly sacred Rig-Veda.

Comment: One important reason I believe is because she was at a time when vedas were being written , and vedas were not finalized and consolidated as such .
If a girl today issued a sanskrit mantra, i don't think it wud be included in any vedas

Comment: Yes , but as youn can see she was Brahma-Vadini. And the ashvins themselves helped her upon her request. So Ved-Vyasa must have sensed this special phenomenon and given it a place in Sacred texts. Anyway but these are also a kind of like invocation or prayer. And since ,by hearing this a miracle happened , it has special significance.

Comment: yes definitely very inspiring also